# xquery finding records with specific security role

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to find records with a specific security role, and I cna't seem to find a way to do it using cts:search (which should be faster than a for loop).  Here is the for loop:

```
let $validRoleList := (
    xdmp:role("myRole1"),
    xdmp:role("myRole2")
)
for $recordUri in cts:uris((), (), cts:collection-query("bigCollection"))
let $documentPermissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($recorduri)/sec:role-id/fn:string()
let $intPermissions := 
    for $permissionValue in $documentPermissions
    return xs:unsignedLong($documentPermissions)
where $intPermissions eq $validRoleList
return $recordUri
```

With my "bigCollection" being in the 15 million record range, even on the task server it's taking over an hour.  Is there any easier way to find a record by its permission role name?

Answer (score 1):

I found this function somewhere years ago, and I don't know how it works, but it does. I've used it in production systems for years, and it works great for your question of "How do I query for documents that have a particular permission?" It's in XQuery, but I believe there's a JS equivalent for each XQuery function.

```
declare function permission-query($role, $capability)
{
  cts:term-query(
    xdmp:add64(
      xdmp:mul64(xdmp:add64(xdmp:mul64(xdmp:role($role), 5), xdmp:hash64($capability)), 5),
      xdmp:hash64("permission()")
    )
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This looping approach is inherently slow because it's going to pull every document off disk to extract its permissions. 15 million docs means 15 million disk fetches. No matter the code, that's slow.

The fastest and easiest way to answer this would be to make and become a user with those two roles and do a `cts:uris` query for all the URIs in the database, and the answer will be automatically and efficiently limited the URIs visible for those two roles.

If you need it more dynamic without creating such a user, it's possible for an admin user to `xdmp:login` with a list of roles.